# I have a low temperature array in javascript and I need to get the lowest temp so I used the min.math function

Tags: javascript, function, min

I have a low temperature array in javascript and I need to get the lowest temp so I used the math.min function. The first time though the low temp is returned and then after that I get NaN.

```
var lowTempArray = []; 
var lowest = Math.min(lowTempArray);

message += '<tr><td colspan="3"class="alt">The lowest temperature of ' + lowest.toFixed(2) + ' occurred on ' + ((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (date.getDate()) + '/' +  date.getFullYear()) + '.' + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: this is a really simple web search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Math.min` only takes a series of numbers, I'd advise just sorting the array and then taking the first element.

So you could do

```
lowTempArray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
var lowest = lowTempArray[0];
```

then use `lowest.toFixed(2)` in your other statement.

cheers :)

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked great! Hey, do you know how to get the date for that input? I think I need to use indexOf for the item in the low temp and then somehow call that same indexed number for the date object. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Oh, and the number was returned as a string so I had to use parselnt:         lowest = parseInt(lowest, 10);

Comment: im not sure what youre asking in terms of the date.  That might be a different question.  At the very least you'll need to elaborate.

Comment: It is so I will just ask a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since `min` wants an argument list, not an array, you can use `apply` to use an array as the argument list for a function, so for example:

```
var arr=[4,5,6,3,1,7,8];
Math.min.apply(this,arr); //1
```

See more on apply:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min` will want a series of number like `Math.min( 1,2,3,4,5 )` and not an array;

You will have to iterate through the array manually like this:

```
var lowest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for ( var i = 0; i < lowTempArray.length; i++ ) {
    if ( lowTempArray[i] < lowest ) {
        lowest = lowTempArray[i];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Let me rewrite it into a function:

```
function lowest( arr ) {
    var lowest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] < lowest ) {
            lowest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var lowest = lowest( lowTempArray );
```

Sorting is also a way, as others have suggested, but it might take more CPU-power when going through a long list.

Comment: Is there a function you can use to get the min amount out of an array? This array is created though the user's input.

Comment: The code I wrote above will give set the lowest value in `lowTempArray` in the variable `lowest`

Comment: Thanks. Yes the for loop is a good choice and you are probably right about sorting and the CPU stress.